# iOS native share - Remove sharing options like Linkedin

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivity

I'm using a native share to share an image from my app. I've removed unwanted options using **excludedActivityTypes**. Some apps like Linkedin (which is installed on my device) pops up on native sharing options. How can I remove these unwanted applications without turning off these apps manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIActivityController` has an `excludedActivityTypes` property. In there you can set an array of `NSStrings` with the identifiers of the activities you want to disable.

You can get LinkedIn's identifier by setting the `completionWithItemsHandler` property on the controller, and logging the string that's passed to that block.

[Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/)

Comment: Is there a way to create an ActivityType with the identifier so that I can use it in the excludedActivityTypes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in `UIActivityViewController`. Try to implement your own. Or look at [existing](https://github.com/overshare/overshare-kit) [projects](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit).